Azure OpenAI: Where are Assistants API persistent resources stored?
When interacting with the Assistants Api, some persistent resources are created, namely: Assistants, Threads and Messages. All have an unique ID and the API exposes methods/endpoints to retrieve these resources.
I can't find anywhere in the documentation an explanation of this persistency:

where is the data stored?
for how long?
is there a cost associated with this?
is gdpr compliant?


I've received an answer by @AshokPeddakotla-MSFT in the Microsoft Learn forum. The link to the thread is here.
TLDR:

where is the data stored?

There are two types of data stored in the Assistants API:
Stateful entities: Threads, messages, and runs created during Assistants use.
Files: Uploaded during Assistants setup or as part of a message.
Data is stored in a secure, Microsoft-managed storage account that is logically separated.

for how long?

All used data persists in this system unless you explicitly delete this data. Use the delete function with the thread ID of the thread you want to delete. Clearing the Run in the Assistants Playground does not delete threads, however deleting them using delete function will not list them in the thread page.

is there a cost associated with this?

Storage has no direct cost related to it. For more information, see the pricing page.

is gdpr compliant?

The Assistant API adheres to relevant data protection regulations, such as GDPR and CCPA, to ensure that user data is handled responsibly and in compliance with applicable laws.
